# Facebook Connect Login Dialog

Tags: javascript, facebook

I've just implemented the Facebook connect successfully. Still I need to do one more thing.

When users clicks on the connect button and a Facebook Login dialog box appears but if user cancel the pop-up instead of login then it navigates away from my site, it goes to the Facebook page. But I want it to stay on my website when clicks on the Cancel.

Please advise me as earliest. Waiting for your reply !!!

Answer (score 0):

If you need more control you can use the FB.login function instead of the  button.

Since you already have your FB SDK init stuff working you should be able to just use this instead.

It's easy to use just do something like:

```
<a onclick="logmein();">Log In</a>

function logmein(){

  FB.login(function(response){
    if (response.status==='connected') { 
      alert('logged in'):
    } else { alert('not logged in'); }

  },{scope:settings.permissions});

}
```

This shouldn't cause any redirection off your site.  Just open's a popup and then use the connected status to verify.  The above code uses the new oAuth 2.0 init so you'll want to make sure your Facebook init is doing the new 2.0 stuff.